# Symfony2 $this->getUser() returns null after manually logging in

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, authentication

From an Angularjs web application I am manually loggin in users to a Symfony controller like this:

```
$em   = $this->getDoctrine();
$repo = $em->getRepository("EMDataBundle:User");
$user = $repo->findOneBy(array('email' => $params['email'])); //$params['email'] contains the user input email
if(!$user)
{
  //user does not excists, return error
  $result = array(
    'success' => false,
    'error'   => 'Username or password doesnt match.'
  );
}
else
{
  $encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
  $encoder         = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
  $password        = $encoder->encodePassword($params['password'], $user->getSalt());
  if($user->getPassword() == $password)
  {
    //login user
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());
    $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token); //now the user is logged in
    $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

    //now dispatch the login event
    $request = $this->get("request");
    $event   = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

    $result = array(
      'success'   => true,
      'email'     => $this->getUser()->getEmail(),
      'firstName' => $this->getUser()->getFirstName(),
      'insertion' => $this->getUser()->getInsertion(),
      'lastName'  => $this->getUser()->getLastName(),
      'roles'     => $this->getUser()->getRoles(),
    );
  }
  else
  {
    //password doesnt match, return error
    $result = array(
      'success' => false,
      'error'   => 'Username or password doesnt match...'
    );
  }
}
$response = new Response(json_encode($result));
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, X-Requested-With');
    return $response;
```

My firewall in security.yml is like this:

```
firewalls:
    main:
      anonymous: ~
      pattern: ^/

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: _demo_login
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/1.0/Organisation, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /api/1.0/Authenticate, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

So far so good. I get the response from the server with the email, firstName, insertion, lastName and roles as it is stored in the database for the user.
The problem I encounter is when I call the next page. When I call $this->getUser() from the backend on a next Angularjs $http call it is null.

Am I on the right track and just missing something small or am I waaaaay off?
Can someone explain to me why it's not working and perhaps give me an idea of what I should do.

Comment: Does your next page is in the same firewall ?

Comment: Hi Ulti, The first request is to the /api/1.0/Authenticate route and the second request goes to the /api/1.0/Organisation/list route